# Understanding Where I Went Wrong in a Linear Conservation Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation

I have the following physics problem.

In the figure below, a stationary block explodes into two pieces L and R that slide across a frictionless floor and then into regions with friction, where they stop. Piece L, with a mass of 2.0 kg, encounters a coefficient of kinetic friction $μ_L$ = 0.40 and slides to a stop in distance $d_L$ = 0.15 m. Piece R encounters a coefficient of kinetic friction $μ_R$ = 0.50 and slides to a stop in distance $d_R$ = 0.20 m. What was the mass of the original block?

[image]

I have a solutions manual and can understand the solution to this problem, but that doesn’t seem to help me understand exactly what I did wrong to begin with, and for this reason I don’t think I’m really learning, I’m just learning how they solved it correctly. I was hoping that I could explain how I approached the problem (it was invalid), and somebody out there could explain to me why what I was doing was wrong intuitevley so that I will not make the same mistake. It’s just hard to learn if you don’t know what you did wrong, so I’ll explain my approach below.

My Approach:

So I know that there are no external forces acting on the system, so the linear momentum is conserved. So $P_i = P_f$. Now after the explosion there are two pieces that travel some distance in opposite directions, so I thought that our linear momentum could be modeled something like this: $mv = m_L v_L + m_R v_R $ which will equal zero because $mv = 0$ (ie the block is initially at rest)

Next I noticed that the coefficient of kinetic friction and distance traveled is given so I thought that I could calculate the positive work in one direction and the negative direction in the other direction and this must be equal because the change in time for each block (ie left and right) will be the same. So I thought about it like this $\Delta t \cdot W_R = \Delta t \cdot W_L$. I then proceeded to solve for the mass of the right block given this equation (ie first cancel $\Delta t$ and then solve). Can someone please explain why this is an invalid approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your last argument is wrong. The work done against the friction need not be equal and there is no time term in the equation. The work done by each force before it comes to stop will depend on its mass and initial kinetic energy. Since it comes to stop, the work done against friction by each block will be equal to its kinetic energy after the explosion. Moreover, the time taken by them will also not be related in any way, i.e. will depend on the mass of the fragment, and coefficient of friction which will determine the deceleration and hence the time taken to come to a stop. Instead you can setup equations as follows:-
using conservation of momentum
$$m_R\vec {v_R}=-m_L\vec {v_L}$$
and using conservation of energy
$$\frac12 m_R(v_R)^2 +\frac12 m_L(v_L)^2=(m_R)(g)\mu_R d_R + (m_L)(g)\mu_L d_L$$
where $g$ is the gravity and this is just the force (maximum static friction) times the distance for each block.